# how GridBagLayout works?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am new to the topic of `GridBagLayout` and I am unable to understand what is the exact difference between the constraints `weight` and `fill`.

Can I `fill` without assigning `weight`.

> Unless you specify at least one non-zero value for weightx or weighty,
>   all the components clump together in the center of their container.
>   This is because when the weight is 0.0 (the default), the
>   GridBagLayout puts any extra space between its grid of cells and the
>   edges of the container.

My question is that, if this is true then why there is no space between the components and they looked attached?

Comment: http://blue-walrus.com/2011/12/gridbaglayout-tutorial/

Comment: @OliverWatkins thanks it seems interesting,i will read it surely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`weightx/y` specifies the amount of "weight" a given cell will have.  The greater the weight, the more space the cell will want to occupy.  The amount of space available is the remaining left over space after all the other components have been laid out.

`fill` determines how the component will expand to occupy the space available to a given cell.   That is, if you have two components in the same column, you can use `fill` set to either `HORIZONTAL` or `BOTH` to allow the component(s) to "expand" to fill the available space of the column, for example...

[image: Short][image: Long]

This, obviously will also work for components in the same row and using `VERTICAL` or `BOTH`

An example with the `Short` button set to `fill` `BOTH` and with it's `weightx` and `weighty` set to `1`.  The short button wants to occupy all the remaining space of the container.

[image: Weighted]

Make sure you have a read through [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

> My question is that, if this is true then why there is no space between the components and they looked attached?

`GridBagLayout` won't add any spacing between components by default, but you can specify spacing through the `insets` property

Answer (score 2):

"Weight" is how much extra place takes the component.
"Fill" is whether the component must fill the extra place or not (should the component be expanded to fill the whole place or not). If it should not fill the extra place you can use "anchor" to determine the position of component (left-bounded, right-bounded, centered)

Comment: this means if you are not assigning a Weight,Fill will have no effect as the component takes no extra space?

Comment: No. If you have two components in the same column, one which is wider than the other, `fill` (specifically set to `HORIZONTAL` or `BOTH`) will ensure that the component (with the `fill` attribute) will expand to fill the cell, overriding it's preferred width.  The same goes for columns in the same row when using `VERTICAL` or `BOTH` `fill` values

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you. your explanation is correct and better than mine